# Calculate percentage dynamically on click of legend

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am working on a column range chart where I have constructed a circle that has a percentage inside it which is before each bar. The percentage is calculated based on the available data labels. For constructing a circle before each bar I have used **chart.renderer.circle**. And for adding a percentage inside it I have used a **chart.renderer.text**

The issue which I am facing is

1. When clicking on legend it should calculate percentage dynamically based on the visible data labels.
2. And, if both the legends are clicked then it should hide the circle along with percentage.

Here is the code along with initial [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/kaL9n2hz/257/)

```
function dynamicCircle(chart){
   var total = chart.series[0].points.reduce(function (accumulator, val) { return accumulator + Math.abs(val.low); }, 0);
  if(chart.series[1].visible){
    var total = total + chart.series[1].points.reduce(function (accumulator, val) { return accumulator + val.high; }, 0);  
  }

   
   chart.series[0].points.forEach(function (p, index) {
                var x = chart.plotSizeX - chart.plotLeft - 20;
                 
                var y = p.dataLabel.alignAttr.y + chart.plotTop + 14.5//p.dataLabel.alignAttr.y + 60;
               
              var datax1 = p.low;
              var numerator;
              if(chart.series.length > 1){
                var datax2 = chart.series[1].points[index].high;
                numerator = Math.abs(datax1) + datax2;
               }else{
                 numerator = Math.abs(datax1);
               }
              var percentage = Math.round((numerator/total) * 100) + "%";
                  
               
           var circle = chart.renderer.circle(x ,y,20)
                  .attr({
                    fill: 'transparent',
                    stroke: '#0494fe',
                    'stroke-width': 2
                  }).add();
                 
                        
           var  percent = chart.renderer.text(percentage, x, y +4 )
                .css({
                   color: '#262e38',
                   fontSize: '14px',
                   fontWeight: 'bold',
                   'text-anchor': "middle",
                   fontFamily: 'proxima_nova_regular'
                }).add(); 
                 
        })
               
}


$('#container1').highcharts({

  chart: {
          type: 'columnrange',
          inverted: true,
          marginLeft: 240,
            events: {
              load: function() {
              dynamicCircle(this)
                
              },
            }
        },
        
        title: {
            text: ""
        },

        
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Physics', 'Computer Science', 'Maths'],
            labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            align:'left',
           //distance: 10,
            reserveSpace: true,
              formatter: function () {
                return this.value ;
              },
               style: {
              // color: '#f2f5f8',
                fontSize: '14px',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
              }
            },
         //   minorTickLength: 0,
   tickLength: 0,
    plotLines: [{
      color: '#ccd6eb',
      width: 1,
      value: 2.5,
      zIndex: 5
    }]
           
        },
        yAxis: {
           title: {
              text: null
          },
          //visible: true,
          labels: {
              formatter: function () {
                  return Math.abs(this.value) ;
              }
          } 
    },
          tooltip: {
           outside: true,
           stickOnContact: true,
           useHTML: true,
            shared: true,
            formatter: function () {
              var labels = "";
              var total;
              var low = this.points[0].point.low;
              if(this.points.length > 1){
                total = Math.abs(low) + this.points[1].point.high + "<br/>";
              }else{
                var totalVal = low != 0 ? Math.abs(low) : this.points[0].point.high;
                total = totalVal + "<br/>";
              }

              labels += "Total " + total; 
              $.each(this.points, function(index, point) {
                var series_name = point.series.name;
                var y = point.point.low != 0 ? Math.abs(point.point.low) : point.point.high;
                label = series_name;
                labels +=  label + '  ' + y + '</br>';
              });

              return labels;
    },
          }, 

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        credits: {
           enabled: false
        },
        
        plotOptions: {
        
             
           columnrange: {
           // pointWidth: 50,
          //  borderWidth: 0,
          //  minPointLength: 60,
               stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true,
                //align: 'center',
                  inside: false,
                  style: {
                  //  verticalAlign: 'middle'
                  },
                  formatter: function() {
                      var series = this.series.chart.series,xPos = this.point.x,filteredSeries;

                      if (this.y != 0) {
                        filteredSeries = series.filter((s) => (s.yData[xPos]));
          return filteredSeries.length > 1 ? Math.abs(this.y) : '';
        }
      }
              },
            }
        },
        
           series: [{
                 name: 'Before',
                 color: 'red',
                 data: [
          [-103,0],[ -487, 0], [-2355, 0]
                 ]
             }, {
                 name: 'After',
                 color: 'green',
                 data: [
            [0,68],[0,102], [0,690]
                 ]
             }] 
           
});
```

I tried  [using](https://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/kaL9n2hz/258/) series show & hide events in plot options. The approach which I am taking is I am hiding the attributes whenever I click on any legend and doing the calculation based on the available data labels. But by doing this I am facing other weird issues. Also, I tried to use destroy() on dynamic elements but it is giving me different errors. Any suggestions will be appreciated

Highchart Version: 7.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some changes in your code - please check if it is a result which you wanted to achieve.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3shget7v/

The main change - use the `render` rather than `load` callback:

```
  chart: {
    type: 'columnrange',
    inverted: true,
    marginLeft: 240,
    events: {
      render: function() {
        dynamicCircle(this)

      },
    }
  },
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Other changes:

```
if (p.customCircle || percentage === '0%') {
  p.customCircle.destroy();
}
```

---

```
if (p.customPercent || percentage === '0%') {
  p.customPercent.destroy();
}
```

---

```
if (percentage === '0%' && p.customPercent && p.customCircle) {
  p.customPercent.hide();
  p.customCircle.hide();

}
```

Comment: Wedzel. Thanks for the answer and your solution is correct. I also found the solution but in a different way https://jsfiddle.net/anikettiwari/kaL9n2hz/280/ but your solution looks elegant